# Codeception( chrome ) : Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, codeception

Hi everyone i updated chrome to the latest version. And since i always get this error when i try to run any test's. Here is the full error :

---

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.89)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: '*.slsteen.dev.nil', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c6a:e098:360d:6eb3%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.5', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b), userDataDir=/var/folders/8j/cd00cwln63q0cv1v7r0_jy_d25jm01/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.joiw47}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=62.0.3202.89, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: f28919671b496f648481a289de8eef5c
```

Comment: It might help if you update your chromedriver to version 2.33, you're on version 2.31 right now.

Comment: I did try that. I'm not sure why it says that im on 2.31 right now... I Tried doing it with npm install chrome driver. It did say that i am on 2.33 but i also got this at the end : npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/package.json'
npm WARN user No description
npm WARN user No repository field.
npm WARN user No README data
npm WARN user No license field.